# Django импорт с соседнего приложения

Tags: python, django

Перепробовал много вариантов тут, но не получается решить проблему.

структура:

```
|engine
|
|__controlcore|
|             |_models.py (def test() )
|__siteapi____
|             |_view.py (def prtn() )
|__engine
|
|manage.py
```

везде пустые `__init.py__`

мне нужно импортировать функцию `test()` из `app controlcore` в `app siteapi/view.py`

`\engine\controlcore\models.py`

```
def test ():
    return 'меня передали'
```

`\engine\siteapi\views.py`

```
from ..controlcore.models import test

    def prtn (request):
        print(test())
```

вываливается ошибка:

```
from ..controlcore.models import test
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: `controlcore` - это приложение созданное через `django-admin startapp controlcore`?

Comment: кмк, должно работать просто `from controlcore.models import test`

Comment: @5c0rp через python manage.py startapp controlcore

Comment: from controlcore.models import test это работает!!! Не понял юмора,  PyCharm подчеркивает ошибку, но это работает, чё за дела???

Comment: @АндрейИванов А в `INSTALLED_APPS` приложение добавлено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, вчера совершенно случайно наткнулся на решение этой проблемы. Дело в том, что PyCharm по умолчанию не воспринимает директории верхнего уровня и для того, что бы явно задать ему эту директорию нужно сделать следующее: ПКМ на директорию верхнего уровня, в моём случае 'engine', Mark directory as - Source root. Теперь PyCharm видит другие app и даже сам экспортирует модули.